# opencv static library with threading building blocks?

Tags: opencv, tbb

I'm trying to build opencv as static library with threading building blocks enabled. I disabled 'BUILD_SHARED_LIBS' and I'm getting usable static opencv libraries, but when I use them to build another app, the resulting app still requires tbb.dll

How can I build the static opencv libraries with TBB enabled, but with tbb statically linked as well?